# assembly language find the last one number

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32, masm32

I want to disassemble a string of numbers to do calculations.

This is my code

```
.data

    r DWORD ?
    sum DWORD 0
    arr DWORD 5 dup(0)
    id DWORD ?
.code

    mov eax,0
    mov ecx,5
    mov edi,offset arr

    L1:
       mov edx,0
       mov eax,id
       call writeint
       mov ebx,10
       div ebx
       mov r,edx ; Quotient
       mov edx,r
       mov id,edx ;
       mov eax,r ;remainder
       mov [edi],eax
       call writeint
       add edi,4    
       LOOP L1
```

I don't know why the id value cannot be saved to eax.

If I input 12345, the id of the second run should be 1234, but it is displayed as 5.

Comment: _"If I input 12345, the id of the second run should be 1234"_ Why? You never use the quotient of the division (`eax`).

Comment: It seems that you confused quotient(EAX) and remainder(EDX). See [here (DIV r/m32)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div).

Comment: I change the code. mov r eax (quotient). mov sum edx (remainder). But I displayed them, remainder value always equal quotient.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want the code to do on each iteration and can you show the implementation of writeint